# Querying inside a Dataset C#

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, rowfilter, defaultview

I have an ADO.NET dataset which is set by a certain query,
say

```
SELECT ID,USER,PRODUCT,COUNT FROM PRODUCTION
```

Without using a where clause I need to derive some results from the dataset. Say I want to get the User and Product count of the user who has the maximum product count. (And I want to do it by using the existing dataset. I can't derive this from dataset.)

Any idea of a way to query inside the dataset? Since there are Datatables my thought was there is some way to query it.

Comment: `DataTable.Compute` is best when you need `count(*)` or `max(COUNT)` like operations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traditional SQL queries cannot be applied to the DataSet. The following *is* possible, however:

- Filter rows using [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) for detailed information about expressions in DataTables.
- Calculate totals etc. using [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx).
- If these two don't do the trick, there's always LINQ.

**Quick-and-dirty LINQ example:** (which doesn't return a DataTable, but a list containing an anonymous type):

```
var joinedResult = dataTable1
  // filtering:
  .Select("MyColumn = 'value'")
  // joining tables:
  .Join(
    dataTable2.AsEnumerable(), 
    row => row.Field<long>("PrimaryKeyField"), 
    row => row.Field<long?>("ForeignKeyField"),
    // selecting a custom result:
    (row1, row2) => new { AnotherColumn = row1.Field<string>("AnotherColumn") });
```

[`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) converts a DataTable into an [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) on which LINQ queries can be performed. If you are new to LINQ, check out [this introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397933%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method.

```
DataTable table = DataSet1.Tables["Orders"];
    // Presuming the DataTable has a column named Date.
    string expression;
    expression = "Date > #1/1/00#";
    DataRow[] foundRows;

    // Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
    foundRows = table.Select(expression);

    // Print column 0 of each returned row.
    for(int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foundRows[i][0]);
    }
```

Also see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx).

Comment: How about getting the Max count... I mean cant I have much advanced query like "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM .... "

Comment: You can get count using .Length. For more advanced one use Linq - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387004.aspx

Comment: @JCTLK: Here is how you count: `.Expression = "Count(OrderID)"`. Explore [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cabd21yw%28vs.71%29.aspx) property.

Comment: @KMan : If you use DataColumn.Expression, you need a column to display count right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do cross-table queries of a Dataset object using LINQ to DataSet:

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386969.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386969.aspx)